# Edit a input element inside a collapsible widget in JQuery Mobile

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I tried to design a form, which is now to complicated for me to describe so I created a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tLh72acj/

I think this shows my problem: I can't access the radio-input:

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true">
     <input type="radio" name="bestellart" value="vor" id="vor" checked />
     <label for="vor">CAN'T</label>
     <input type="radio" name="bestellart" value="eil" id="eil" />
     <label for="eil">TOUCH</label>
     <input type="radio" name="bestellart" value="ewg" id="ewg" />
     <label for="ewg">THIS!</label>
</fieldset>
```

I want to control the radio buttons when I click on them, but if I click on any other place inside the collapsible I want it to open (but not if I use the radio buttons). How do I have to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what you want ?

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tLh72acj/1/)

```
if ($(this).closest(".ui-collapsible").hasClass('ui-collapsible-collapsed')){
    $(this).closest(".ui-collapsible").collapsible({collapsed: false});
}
else{
    $(this).closest(".ui-collapsible").collapsible({collapsed: true});
}
```

Here is an update with comments : [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tLh72acj/2/)